# How to reorder the div elements (already rendered) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to sort the below div elements based on fare values. I need to sort based on key:value pair which look like `[{key:"1",value=""},{..},{..}]`.

The below snippet is my HTML code

```
<div class="panel data" key="1" fare="800"></div>
<div class="panel data" key="2" fare="300"></div>
<div class="panel data" key="3" fare="500"></div>
```

the below structure is how the output I wanted.

```
[
  {key:"2",value:"300"},
  {key:"3",value:"500"},
  {key:"1",value:"800"}
]
```

Also I need to reorder the div as per above structure.

Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Why reorder instead of rewrite?

Comment: did you try to get data to array and sort while in array here is the solution you may interested in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript]

Comment: I need to sort based on numeric values. I tried to sort but its not ordering properly.

Comment: Jonas W. Please guide me how to do it. Since im new to jquery please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```js
document.querySelector( "#sortByFare" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   var panels = document.querySelectorAll( ".panel.data" );
   [].slice.call( panels ).sort( function(a,b){ 
     var aFare = a.getAttribute( "fare" );
     var bFare = b.getAttribute( "fare" );
     if ( aFare < bFare )
     {
        a.parentNode.insertBefore( a, b );
     }
     else
     {
        a.parentNode.insertBefore( b, a );
     }
     return aFare - bFare;
   });
});
```

```html
<div class="panel data" key="1" fare="800">800
</div>
<div class="panel data" key="2" fare="300">300
</div>
<div class="panel data" key="3" fare="500">500
</div>

<input type="button" value="Sort By Fare" id="sortByFare"/>
```

It can be generalized further if you refactor the sorting logic as

```js
document.querySelector( "#sortByFare" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   var panels = document.querySelectorAll( ".panel.data" );
   sortDomElements( panels, "fare" );
});

document.querySelector( "#sortByKey" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   var panels = document.querySelectorAll( ".panel.data" );
   sortDomElements( panels, "key" );
});

function sortDomElements( nodeList, attributeName )
{
  [].slice.call( nodeList ).sort( function(a,b){ 
     var aFare = a.getAttribute( attributeName );
     var bFare = b.getAttribute( attributeName );
     if ( aFare < bFare )
     {
        a.parentNode.insertBefore( a, b );
     }
     else
     {
        a.parentNode.insertBefore( b, a );
     }
     return aFare - bFare;
   });
}
```

```html
<div class="panel data" key="1" fare="800">800
</div>
<div class="panel data" key="2" fare="300">300
</div>
<div class="panel data" key="3" fare="500">500
</div>

<input type="button" value="Sort By Fare" id="sortByFare"/>

<input type="button" value="Sort By Key" id="sortByKey"/>
```

Comment: Its not working for large number of data. Its reordering in wrong way.

Comment: @CharanKumar how many number of items? How did you replicated?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have them within a parent element
you could pick all the child element and loop over comparing the values and build a rewrite string.

```
var parentEl= document.getElelemtById('parentID')
    for (var j = 0; j < parentEl.childNodes.length; j++) {
            var key = parentEl.childNodes[j].getAttribute('key');
            var fare = parentEl.childNodes[j].getAttribute('fare');
             // compare the fare  here
             // also build your new child div strings here
        }
             // finally output the new child string
             parentEl.innerHTML= yourNewChildString;
```

Have not tested this, but it should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="listing-item" data-fare="800">800</div>
    <div class="listing-item" data-fare="300">300</div>
    <div class="listing-item" data-fare="500">500</div>     
</div>



 var divList = $(".listing-item");
divList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).data("fare")-$(b).data("fare")});

$("#list").html(divList);
```

Comment: It works properly. But it will affect my javascript fuction because reassigning the html data doesn't loaded in DOM.

Comment: inside "listing-item" div element. I have plenty of elements which generates from the c#.